# Defining single function to handle functionality of other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to define a single function that handles the functionality provided by setSlide, setMobile, and hide and just pass in the function to be called by SetTimeout when the delay has occurred. I'm not sure how to do this. Can someone please explain how to accomplish this? Thank you.

```
(function($) {
var currentTime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

var setSlide = function (timeout) {
    setTimeout(showSlide, timeout * 1000);
},
showSlide = function () {
    $('.newsletter-popup').addClass('slide-left');
},
setMobile = function (timeout) {
    setTimeout(showMobile, timeout * 1000);
},
hide = function (timeout) {
    setTimeout(hideMobile, timeout * 1000);
},
showMobile = function () {
    $('.newsletter-popup').removeClass('hidden');
},
hideMobile = function () {
    $('.newsletter-popup').addClass('hidden');
};
$(document).ready(function() {

    if (readCookie('nl_suppress')) {
        $('.newsletter-popup').removeClass('slide-left');
    } else if (!readCookie('nl_display')) {
        setSlide(10);
    } else if (currentTime - readCookie('nl_display') > 86400) {
        showSlide();
    } else {
        setSlide(currentTime - (readCookie('nl_display') + 86400));
    }

    $('.nlForm').submit(function() {
        createCookie('nl_suppress', new Date(), 30);
    });

    function checkCookie() {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (86400000));
        $('.newsletter-popup').removeClass('slide-left');
        hide(1);

        if(readCookie('nl_display')) {  
            // already been clicked once, hide it
            createCookie('nl_suppress', new Date(), 180);
            return;
        } 
        // first time this is clicked, mark it
        createCookie('nl_display', new Date().getTime() / 1000, 180);
        setMobile(14);
        setSlide(15); 
    };

    $('.newsletter-close').on('click', checkCookie);
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you show us what the single function should look like?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to create a function that does the same thing as `setTimeout`, but the delay multiplied by `1000` so that it is in seconds.

It would look like this:

```
function setTimeoutSeconds(func, delay) {
    setTimeout(func, delay * 1000);
}
```

Then instead of calling `setSlide`, `setMobile`, or `hide`, you call `setTimeoutSeconds` with the desired callback.

```
setTimeoutSeconds(hideMobile, 1);
setTimeoutSeconds(showMobile, 14);
setTimeoutSeconds(showSlide, 15);
```

---

If you still wanted to have the `setSlide`... etc functions, you could use a partially applied function:

```
function applyTimeout(func) {
    return function(delay) {
        setTimeout(func, delay * 1000);
    }
}
```

And then create them like this:

```
var setSlide = applyTimeout(showSlide);
```

And then call them the same way:

```
setSlide(15);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple:

```
const callFunctionWithTimeout = (fn, timeout) => setTimeout(fn, timeout * 1000)
```

Then, for example instead of `setSlide(10)`, you do:

```
callFunctionWithTimeout(showSlide, 10)
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly but there was some concern about cross browser support with that option.

Comment: @Chad If you want to have cross-browser support, you can use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to compile your code.